# Qt overriding the tslib calibration constants

Tags: qt

I am running Qt application on F&S armStone a9 board. The application is overriding the ts_calibrate generated constants so that even when I try bad calibration of the touch screen the application is working. What I want is to use the filters generated by tslib? How can I force the qt to use the tslib

I have tried configuring the following environment variables

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib
export TSLIB_TSEVENTTYPE=INPUT
export QTDIR=/usr/lib/qt
export QWS_MOUSE_PROTO=tslib:/dev/input/event1
export TSLIB_CONSOLEDEVICE=none
export TSLIB_FBDEVICE=/dev/fb0
export TSLIB_CALIBFILE=/etc/pointercal
export TSLIB_CONFFILE=/etc/ts.conf
export TSLIB_PLUGINDIR=/usr/lib/ts
export TSLIB_TSDEVICE=/dev/input/event1
export QWS_DISPLAY=LinuxFB:mmWidth=800:mmHeight=480
```

Comment: Be more specific as to what version of Qt that you're using.  BTW your question has nothing to do with the Linux kernel, so fix the tags.

Comment: The qt version I am using is Qt 5.

Comment: You probably need to set the **QT_QPA_FB_TSLIB** (or **QT_QPA_EGLFS_TSLIB**) environment variable.  RTM: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/embedded-linux.html#touch

Comment: Thank you ..... that worked!!

Comment: @sawdust and (at)HariP if it is solved, write an answer and mark it as the solution :)